# BufferedReader giving non-zero exit code

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

**Problem**
A simple programming [question](http://www.codechef.com/problems/MUFFINS3), involves reading a number N, T times from console and perform simple calculation on it.

**Constraints:**

1 ≤ T ≤ 1000

2 ≤ N ≤ 100000000

As BufferedReader is usually faster than Scanner, I used it but the program exited with Non-Zero Exit code whereas using Scanner resolved the issue.

Since both work fine on my computer, I suspect this is a memory issue.

**Questions:**

1. Is my assumption that BufferedReader is faster than Scanner correct?
2. Does BufferedReader use more memory? If yes, is it the reason for the error?

**Code:**

Using BufferedReader, throws error

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (int i=0; i<T; i++) {
            int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            int res = (N/2)+1;
            System.out.println(res);
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

The code using Scanner that returned correct output:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        for (int i=0; i<T; i++) {
            int N = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            int res = (N/2)+1;
            System.out.println(res);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error is thrown in the `BufferedReader` case?

Comment: Since I'm submitting to codechef, I can't know the error. I get no error when I run it on my computer. The error code is NZEC. http://www.codechef.com/wiki/faq#Why_do_I_get_an_NZEC

Comment: Please read the documentation for [`BufferedReader.readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) carefully, in particular what values it can return.

Comment: Been using that for practicing other questions on codechef. Haven't got an error until now so I assume the input format is as described in the question

Comment: Do you get the correct answer with the Scanner solution? The solutions look identical.

Comment: Have you considered running the code locally? There are other ways to debug you know.

Comment: My guess is the error is elsewhere, is that all the code generating the error? Your code reads from standard input each line and writes to the standard output, so effectively it will read the same output it generated. Don't think that's what you really want.

Comment: @EJP Yes, I mentioned in my question "both work fine on my computer"

Comment: @Julio It's a practice question on codechef. The link to the actual problem is there in my question

Comment: If you 'can't know the error', how can you know an error was thrown? And what is the meaning of your mutually contradictory constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As of JDK 7, BufferedReader uses a bigger buffer than Scanner (I think 8192c vs 1024c), so yes it uses more memory, and can make for a faster runtime on large inputs.
2. This might be the source of your problem (or it might be that whoever wrote the tests for this problem has something wrong), since I tested your BufferedReader code myself and cannot see any problems with it.

Comment: 8192 *chars.* Not kilobytes.

Comment: Might be a good idea to change sz from it's default value in new BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz) and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

> Is my assumption that BufferedReader is faster than Scanner correct?

Not in this case, as the speed of your program is limited by how fast you can type. Compared to that, any difference between Scanner and BufferedReader is insignificant.

> Does BufferedReader use more memory?

It isn't specified.

> If yes, is it the reason for the error?

Is it the reason for *what* error? As you didn't post the error you're getting, this question is unanswerable. However I don't see any reason to believe you have a memory problem.

Comment: 1) "limited by how fast you can type".. - I'll run it as java Main < input.txt for benchmarking. In some other questions on codechef when I'm supposed to read a lot of input, I get TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) using Scanner but not with BufferedReader
2) Codechef doesn't give you the error and since it runs fine on my computer I can't think of any other cause of problem.

Comment: 1. Your question clearly states 'from console'. Make up your mind. 2. *Non sequitur.* The fact that you can't think of any other cause doesn't imply that the only cause you thought of is the correct cause.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error you're having(an error on the `BufferedReader`). It's because you forgot to put the `BufferedReader` in a try catch block. I also had the `throws IOException` after the main funtion but that's not enough. So it's not a memory issue.

The correct code could be something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {  
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
             int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
             for (int i=0; i<T; i++) {
             int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
             int res = (N/2)+1;
             System.out.println(res);
        }catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
             try{
                 br.close();
             }catch ( Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        } // end of try catch
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: You 'had the same error [he is] having' such as what?

Comment: read his question, "BufferdReader is throwing error". With codechef you don't know the error, but from his code I can see that he forgot this.